# Combine more $match in one $or in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There is a search that works fine for one column and I want to make it check for the introduced string in two (more) columns.

This is how it works for one:

```
if (req.query.name) {
      aggregateOptions.push({ $match: { name: { $regex: req.query.name, $options: 'i' } } });
}
```

so it checks if the introduced string/substring is present in the **name** column and filters out the columns that don't have it.

I want to add this also for **city** column. So it checks if the introduced string is present in one of **name** or **city** columns, it doesn't have to be in both, only in one it's fine.

So I used `$or` for this:

```
if (req.query.name) {
  aggregateOptions.push({
    $or: [
      { $match: { name: { $regex: req.query.name, $options: 'i' } } },
      { $match: { city: { $regex: req.query.city, $options: 'i' } } },
    ],
  });
}
```

It seems wrong because it doesn't filter anything when a string is introduced in the search box and the returns error 400 and `"$or is not allowed in this atlas tier"`.

How can be this solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. But $or is on the wrong level. Atlas whitelists available stages. Your getting that error since you are using $or as a stage, which it is not.

```
if (req.query.name) {
  aggregateOptions.push({
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { name: { $regex: req.query.name, $options: 'i' } },
        { city: { $regex: req.query.city, $options: 'i' } },
      ],
    }
  });
}
```